# Can I create additional SQL server for testing with SQL server authentication rather than Windows authentication on a single pc?

Tags: sql-server, windows, azure-sql-database, ssms

Testing SQL queries with large datasets against Azure SQL server may be costly, so it is better for me to test my code against a local server. I would like to create a new local server with "SQL Server authentication" rather than "Windows authentication", and I would like to keep my *default* local server that uses Windows authentication.

In lack of better phrasing:... is it "common" to have multiple SQL servers with different authentication methods on the same Windows-10 pc ?

If it is "straight-forward" to do this, then please share "how-to", or share better jargon for web searches. I did not find much information on this when googling "*create new local server with sql server authentication*"

As you may easily catch from the text: I'm not an IT expert...

Comment: Can you do it? Yes. Is it common? IMO not generally (for a non-server machine) because your instances will compete with each other for resources. In [mixed mode authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15), you can use either SQL logins or windows authentication so perhaps you really only need one instance?

Comment: What benefit do you see of having 2 instances over 1 with mixed authentication here?

Comment: As I wrote... I'm not an expert on this, but the code is for an Azure server for which I don't have admin right to. If the code is tested on a server with mixed authentication then still it may fail for SQL Server authentication,... right ?

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Authentication mode only affects the login functionality. It can be switched at any time. But it is your decision and your machine to manage. You can stop either instance to prevent resource contention. You decide how much effort you want to put into this.

Comment: I really don't see the point. I can't see why you need the extra instance: changing login is just a matter for connection strings, not really worth another whole instance. Your bigger issue is going to be features that work locally but not on Azure, there are many.

Comment: @SMor - useful comments

Comment: @Charlieface - I've noticed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use at an instance and solely your will to provide the accesses.
where you can use Windows Authentication mode and mixed mode.

More information about Windows Authentication may be found at: [Connecting Using Windows Authentication.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-through-windows-authentication)

We may utilize [SQL Server Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-through-sql-server-authentication) to solve your problem by passing the user name and password.